# Conserving a state in a large python program without passing variable as parameter

Tags: python

I have a large project where I load in some variables from a config.ini, such as the target_directory of the data that is generated. This target_directory is used all over the project but it is not always set in the same place. It can be set by config.ini, but it can be overridden by command line parameters or also by unit tests.

What is the best way to preserve that state in a global way, so I don't have to pass it into every function of my program.

The program consists of many different modules and packages and I was wondering if there's a best practice how this could be handled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work:

main.py

```
import c2
from c3 import func

c2.v1 = 1
c2.v2 = 1
c2.v3 = 1


def edit():
    c2.v1 = 11

if __name__ == "__main__":
    edit()
    func()
```

c2.py (the configuration container)

```
v1 = 2
v2 = 2
```

c3.py

```
import c2

def func():
    print (c2.v1)
    print (c2.v2)
    print (c2.v3)
```

output:

```
11
1
1
```

Answer (score 2):

You could set state into a module-level variable using a dictionary, or any other type of [container](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html). These values are not static, and can be modified/mutated by any code that has access to them (unless you use an immutable container, like a tuple or namedtuple). You can import the whole `conf.py` module with `import conf`, or just pull in the configuration container with `from conf import CONFIG`

```py
# this is conf.py

import argparse
import configparser

CONFIG = {}

def build_config():
    # ...compose your config from cli, ini file, etc
    CONFIG['option_one'] = 'hello world'
    return CONFIG
```

...

```
# this is a.py
import conf

def do_something_with_config_value():
    return conf.CONFIG['option_one']
```

...

```
# this is b.py

import a
import conf

if __name__ == '__main__':
    conf.build_config()
    print(a.do_something_with_config_value())
```

Comment: If I import conf from another module, would those changes then be visible?

Comment: Generally, yes. But to be certain I would need to see a specific example. I added `b.py` just now to demonstrate this.

Comment: Let's assume conf.py is imported by main.py, which sets CONFIG['state']=1. Then main.py calls a function in sub.py (which imports conf.py). Will the state of CONFIG be set to 1?

Comment: This example is now a bit convoluted. What I want is main.py imports conf.py and changes CONFIG which has to be part of the conf.py module. Then main.py imports sub.py, is which needs to read the CONf value again from conf.py that was previously changed.

Comment: Also it currently has multiple entry points which makes no sense